# Copy S3 object to EC2 instance failed, 403 error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I created an EC2 instance of Ubuntu using CFT, after that I want to copy a WAR file into my instance's folder located at `/someurl/wildfly/standalone/deployments`

this is the command I use:

```
aws s3 cp s3://my/url/to/skcloud.war /someurl/wildfly/standalone/deployments/ --sse
```

This is the error:

```
fatal error: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden
```

What I tried:

```
sudo chmod -R 757 /someurl/wildfly/standalone/deployments/
```

What should I do next to solve this problem? For example, how to check if I have the written access to the war file.

Thanks,

Comment: You don't have access to `s3://my/url/to/skcloud.war`.

Comment: @MarkB I create the Instance using my pem file, I upload the war file with read/write access. "you" means the instance I created? How to grant access to that?

Comment: The pem file is irrelevant. "You" means whatever IAM credentials the AWS CLI tool is using. If you haven't configured any credentials on that server then it would be using the IAM role assigned to the EC2 instance (if you assigned one).

Comment: @MarkB I do have IAM role assigned to that instance, but I don't have the knowledge to that, how to config the role so it can have access to S3? suppose just add this additional access to my previous IAM role.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to access S3 from your instance:
1. Define accessKey/SecretKey in your CFT and when launch new instance, use user-data to save that accessKey/SecretKey into local profile. Then Use this info to access S3. Ofcourse, this accessKey/SecretKey must has permission to access your S3 bucket 
2. Use IAM role that has permission to access your S3 bucket too. Then asign this role to instance when launch by CFT.
Abour permission/policy, look at [This](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-how-to-grant-access-to-an-amazon-s3-bucket/)